# Make \usepackage{polski} and \texttt work in the same document

Tags: fonts, babel, typewriter

I would like to use Polish language in a part of my Acknowledgements.
In order to do it I introduced in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[polish, english]{babel}
```

And later on, to change the language I use:

```
\foreignlanguage{polish}{..}
```

However, I realized, that at the moment I introduce that (specifically the part `\usepackage{polski}`) the `\texttt` stops working. And I need to use it to introduce the DNA sequences.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Can't you simply remove the **outdated package** `polski` completely? Everything should work without it.

Comment: In my experiment there's nothing wrong. Can you provide an example code?

Comment: I build a MWE and it worked. Apparently there was something else in my code that caused the problem. At the end I removed \usepackage{polski} and added \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage{lmodern}. Now everything works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @yo' An answer?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `\usepackage{polski}` altogether and you should be fine. All its functionality is covered by `\usepackage[polish]{babel}`.